# On Document Ready equivalent

Tags: coded-ui-tests

Running Coded UI tests, my tests occasionally fail due to timing issues (control/ HTML element not on page yet).

Is there a "on document ready" equivalent for coded UI tests? Or maybe there's a best practice for handling this issue?

Answer (score 3):

There are several `WaitForControl...` methods that can be used. From your question, `WaitForControlReady` may be appropriate. The other methods include `WaitForControlExist` and `WaitForControlNotExist` that monitor the screen waiting until, respectively, a control appears or is removed; plus several other for more complex situations.

For more details see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gautamg/archive/2010/02/12/how-to-make-playback-wait-for-certain-event.aspx

Comment: Thanks, Adrian. What about making use of the `executeScript` command available in the `BrowserWindow` object? Perhaps it's possible to write a script to only return when the document is ready?

Comment: @Kevin I am not familiar with `executeScript`. Before using it I would suggest ask yourself what are you testing. Are you testing the application as seen by a human using the computer, or are you doing white box testing of the internals of the application?

Answer (score 1):

Use this to wait for the document to be ready.

```
this.PageMapWindow.PageMapDocument.WaitForControlReady()
```

where PageMapWindow and PageMapDocument are names of window and document controls respectively in your UIMap.

Answer (score 0):

@AdrianHHH has the right answer however,

*Sometimes I noticed that if you have continue on error set to true for each step it tends to skip bits, so try turning that off*

Also you could do it the bad way and use

```
Playback.Wait();
```