# Coded UI - Programmatically check if control is blocked?

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

Is there any way to check if a control is blocked before acting on it? I'm having an issue automating a silverlight application.  Certain controls in a table intermittently appear as blocked when playing back when other times they can be accessed.  There does not seem to be any reason for the blockage because it works more often than not. I've tried adding wait statements, I've tried both hand coding the control reference and recording it, I've even tried accessing other parts of the cell and tried tabbing to the cell... it just occasionally appears to be blocked.

To make things trickier, the control only appears to be blocked during playback.  If I run in debug mode, the control is always visible.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of `WaitForControl...` methods that may help. See also [On Document Ready equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17871683/on-document-ready-equivalent/17876840#17876840)